# Can I use Pandas 'read_excel' and with tqdm?

Tags: pandas, tqdm

I'm trying to add a tqdm progress bar to a python script which reads a tab from an excel spreadsheet. I've spent a full day without progress. I'm using pandas to read the file as follows:

```py
in_data = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name=(sheet))
```

I suspect that this is either not do-able, or extremely simple. Thanks so much.

Comment: My suspicion is that you won't be able to - unless you're reading the excel in chunks. `tqdm` tends to need an `iterable` to give progress on each iteration of a loop or similar.

Comment: Agreed. I was not able to succeed using excel_read with tqdm. Fortunately, I found out how to speed up my data read such that I can do without the progress bar. But, my knowledge has been increased by your response, so I'm sincerely grateful and appreciative. Much thanks for your help!